# Cómo extraer la variable de un sitio externo usando file_get_contents

Tags: php

Hola amigos de Stack Overflow , necesito de su ayuda para solucionar este problema.

Necesito encontrar la manera de extraer una variable de un sitio externo y luego utilizarla en mi sito. En este caso es una búsqueda en Google Images, necesito mostrar las imágenes en un `Array` para obtener un listado.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?

$texto = "Búsqueda";$url = " http://images.google.com/search?q=busqueda&tbm=isch ";

$file =file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all("REGULAR EXPRESSION",

// la búsqueda da estos resultados 
http://images.google.es/imgres?imgurl=https://www.busqueda.com/img/
/búsqueda.gif   

//Pero Me gustaría extraer con un $_GET la variable "imgurl' ya que es la que muestra el source de la imagen.

Arrar =>

// mostramos
1- echo $file https://www.busqueda.com/img//búsqueda.gif


2 - echo $file  https://www.busqueda.com/img//búsqueda_1.gif

$matches);

?>
```

No se si es el método adecuado de hacerlo, entiendo que Google tiene una API para las imágenes, pero si pudiese realizarlo de esta manera sería útil. Espero vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con esto y me avisas si te sirve:

```
  <?PHP

  $url = "http://www.elmejorcoche.com";

  $html = file_get_contents($url);

  preg_match_all("/<img[\s]+[^>]*?src[\s]?=[\s\"\']+(.*\.([gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg|tiff]{3,4}))[\"\']+.*?>/", $html, $images);

  $images = $images[1];

  $list = array();

  foreach($images as $img) {

     echo $img."<br>";

  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Funciona Perfectamente! Pero una pregunta, la expresio irregular que utiliza extrae las <src img> de cualquier sitio ?

Comment: Lo he probado en varios sitios y funciona, en otros no resulta. Ahora el código es ese y es cuestión de investigar más, modificarlo y adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Ese código me funciona para un sistema que hice hace algún tiempo y es muy posible que se pueda mejorar.

Comment: Si funciona muy bien, pero al parecer para extraer variables de sitios que impliquen búsqueda no funciona, intentaré modificar espero me de el resultado deseaodeseado

Comment: Acabo de probarlo con esta URL y hasta me sube las fotos: $url = "https://www.google.cl/search?safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=643&q=cara";

Comment: En serio @EduardoMunizaga Podrías Modificar la Respuesta para ver tu nueva modificación?

Comment: Estimado no hice ninguna modificación solo cambié la URL por la del comentario anterior , también probé en la página everystockphoto.com, haciendo una busqueda y copiando la URL en el código y también funcionó. Me  di cuenta que hay páginas que se protegen de esto y por eso no es posible que funcione en todas. Por ejemplo en flickr no se puede, no obstante ellos tienen un Api donde es posible hacerlo en PHP : https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.php.html .

Comment: Es sumamente extraño, me gustaría enviarte mi archivo php para mostrar que he cambiado dicha dirección y otras y no lanza resultados, solamente con el ejemplo original. Pero seguire leyendo creo que a lo mejor es otro el problema

Comment: Dejame el código en tu Dropbox, Driver o servidor público y le doy un vistazo

Comment: Claro aquí esta http://upfile.mobi/1240667

Comment: Esto resulto con tu script : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44676047/respuesta.png , Debe ser alguna configuración del servidor, lo probe en PHP 5.2 y 5.4

Comment: Tengo ganas de llorar porque eso buscó Precisamente :"( sabes creo que Google ha bloqueado la IP del servidor compartido que tengo por eso no funciona... Pero tu escript funciona y de seguro los otros tambien! En resumen es el server donde estoy alojado :/

Comment: AMIGO ERA LA VERSIÓN DE PHP LA CAMBIE Y FUNCIONÓ!!!!  Woow sos todo un Sabio :D ya me funcionó Gracias Infinitas !!!!!!!!

Comment: Excelente. Saludos!

Comment: Hola @EduardoMunizaga Disculpe que vengo a molestar nuevamente, pero solo una ultima consulta. En caso que desee extraer el <a href> de la lista de imágenes que expresión debo utilizar?  Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estimado, no quiero ser pesado pero la verdad creo que tienes que intentar aprenderlo tu mismo para ir superando tu calidad de desarrollador. Te dejo un tutorial que te ayudará y así lo tomas  como desafío: http://www.mmfilesi.com/blog/introduccion-a-las-xpresiones-regulares-en-php/. Saludos. ( en todo caso la respuesta a tu pregunta a parecer la tiene Carlos Huchim)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular.

```
/<a href=[\'"]?\/imgres\?imgurl=([^\'" >]+)/g
```

Que devolverá toda la URL como se muestra en [este ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/rT6mV2/1).

Saludos.

```
<?php

// Establece el contenido recuperado de la solicitud al sitio web de Google.
$contenidoArchivo = '..<a href="/img..indow=this;..';

// La expresión regular contiene caracteres ("\", "'", '"') que deben ser escapados.
// /<a href=[\'"]?\/imgres\?imgurl=([^\'" >]+)/
$busquedaExitosa = preg_match_all("/<a href=[\\\'\"]?\\/imgres\\?imgurl=([^\\\'\" >]+)/", 
    $contenidoArchivo, 
    $resultadosExpresionRegular);

if ($busquedaExitosa)
{   // Recupero los resultados. Los valores se encuentran en el índice 1e los resultados.
    $repositorioImagenes = $resultadosExpresionRegular[1];

    foreach ($repositorioImagenes as $imagen){
        // La URL la devuelve completa, es posible que quieras dividirla
        $partesUrl = explode("&amp;", $imagen);

        // Y usar la primera parte que es la ruta a la imagen.
        var_dump($partesUrl[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero se me dificulta un poco trabajar con expresiones regulares,  revise el ejemplo pero no se como poner en marcha su ejemplo, Me ayudas :)

Comment: @BryanBWeiss ya agregué el ejemplo, espero te sirva y disculpa la tardanza, me distraigo mucho porque es viernes :P

Comment: Jajaja esta bien tomese su tiempo el Viernes todo se vale ,   por cierto es justamente lo que busco! Pero intente probar el código  y en la parte de la consulta coloque la búsqueda` <?php

// Establece el contenido recuperado de la solicitud al sitio web de Google.
$contenidoArchivo = 'http://images.google.com/search?q=busqueda&tbm=isch'; pero no me lanzo resultados ,` que estoy asiendo mal? :S  @CarlosHuchim

Comment: Necesitas implementar la solicitud a la página web para luego almacenar el contenido en esa variable. Por ejemplo: `$contenidoArchivo = file_get_contents('http://images.google.com/search?q=busqu...');`

Comment: agradezco mucho su interés por mi problema :) pero por alguna razón los resultados se niegan a salir, seguir los pasos indicados '$contenidoArchivo = file_get_contents('http://images.google.com/search?q=busqueda); ` pero aún no hay resultados, estoy seguro que no he agregado un caracter mas lo implimento tal como esta. Que podrá estar sucediendo

Comment: La función [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) requiere de una URL válida, que incluya "http://", si la estas incluyendo y no funciona, prueba imprimiendo [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)($contenidoArchivo); para ver que te esta devolviendo, es posible que ahí comience el problema.

Comment: Si incluyo el HTTP pero el foro lo Quita, y estoy realizando las pruebas en un servidor Real, y realize el volcado var_dump a $contenidoArchivo  y aún no pasa nada.  Nada mas un sitio en blanco :/ es triste porque parece que todo esta bien, :/ no se donde pueda estar el problema

Comment: Pues no estoy seguro de que te pueda ayudar mas a detalle, lo que si es importante que sepas, es que Google puede bloquear tu solicitud y no devolverte contenido. Hay que averiguar si el archivo PHP se puede ejecutar, luego verificar si el contenido que devuelve esta en blanco o es otro texto, si es en blanco. Puedes cambiar la URL a otra que no sea Google, para probar si file_get_contents esta funcionando bien. Si no funciona bien, comprobar la configuración a internet de tu servidor. ¡Diviertete!, pero primero prueba eso que te digo, y me dices. :D

Comment: Gracias, amigo seguiremos probando!, de seguro si no es para Google, talvez funcione en otro sitio, muchas Gracias has solventado muchas de mis dudas, te lo agradezco muchoooo